# How to convert special characters in dictionary to unicode in swift

Tags: ios, swift, string, unicode

```
//temporary dictionary
let tempDict =  ["ttTasks":"€ is euro symbol"]
```

//conversion should replace  € symbol with \u20ac

so final dictionary would be

```
finalDict = ["ttTasks":"\u20ac is euro symbol"]
```

NOTE: please do not suggest me `replaceOccurencesOfString` as i need to do this for every special character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
for key in tempDict.keys {
    let data = tempDict[key]?.data(using: String.Encoding.nonLossyASCII)
    tempDict[key] = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
}
```

Comment: one more quick question, i am getting double slash in the output is there anyway i can edit the above code to get single slash.  ["ttTasks": "\\u20ac"]

Comment: @user431791 did you fix this two slash issue